# Add timestamp AFTER a edit function is run in the target sheet-Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My first task was to move data from one sheet to another when a certain entry is made in a certain column. That I did successfully taking help from online sources.
The next task is to add a timestamp to the now moved data(in target sheet). I have tried multiple ways to do that but it's not working at all. I have added my code below, what am I doing wrong?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Task" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DoneTask");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  else if (s.getName() == "DoneTask" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Done")
  {var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);
  nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
```

I think it's because the active sheet is still the "Task" sheet and so the elseif is not working, but I don't know how to verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see why you would put this in a an else if. Seems like you want to stamp the date when the if statement runs? 
Try this.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Task" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DoneTask");
    var lr = targetSheet.getLastRow();
       var target = targetSheet.getRange(lr +1 , 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange(lr + 1, numColumns +1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I was using else if as I thought I should first have the first condition fulfilled. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries! Happy to help.